# Helmholtz coil (cancelation on of earth magnetic field)

Tags: electromagnetism

How the Helmholtz coil cancels the earth magnetic field. Can anyone explain it pictorially?

Comment: have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil

Answer (score 1):

A Helmholtz coil produces a fairly uniform magnetic field in the region near the center of the two coils.  To cancel the Earth's field (in that region), the coils would have to be oriented with the Earth's field along the axis of the coils. (Don't forget the dip in the Earth's field.)